# cannot update certain entries, error 1064

Tags: wygwam, error, php-errors

My site was working just fine, when all of a sudden editing certain pages lead to the error below.
Now it seems as if i'm also not able to create entries in that channel anymore. After hitting submit i keep getting these errors.

Help is geatly appreciated, since this is a live site...

i am running EE 2.8.1

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Transfer Needs for Europe's Biggest Sides in Summer,229,682,725,193,188,447,109,' at line 3

SELECT entry_id, channel_id, title, url_title, status FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE entry_id IN (1,303,55,305,103,166,170,168,167,165,4,2,466,56,726,8,13,64,5,169,106,65,174,3,63,306,100,727,186,58,14,420,753,242,489,236,286,327,256,250,549,255,247,323,258,15 Transfer Needs for Europe's Biggest Sides in Summer,229,682,725,193,188,447,109,77,432) ORDER BY entry_id DESC

Filename: /path/to/public_html/assets/addons/wygwam/helper.php

Line Number: 1200

Comment: What version of Wygwam are you running? Also, what version of PHP and MySQL are you running? It might help us uncover the problem.

Comment: i'm running 3.3.3 as of an hour ago. However, i'm not sure wygwam is at fault here. I see there's an entry title in what i suppose should be and array of id's.
I deleted that entry in EE, and can't find it in the database anymore. however, the error still shows

Answer (score 3):

[image]"Transfer Needs for Europe's Biggest Sides in Summer" isn't an entry_id and should not be in the where in clause.

Wygwam is pulling those entry ids from EE's page ids.

Check the page module and any config overrides.

Comment: page module isn't installed, structure is used. I don't see anything in the config that could have anything to do with this error. (might be i don't know what to look for)
When i change the fieldtype to vanilla txtare the error goes away, when i change it back to wygwam the error is back. Which is to be expected.
I think i know how the titel (Transfer Needs etc) got into the id field. I deleted the entry. cleared caches etc. wygwam still throws the error even though the string is not in the DB anymore